# Remove textfield from checkoutpage-IWD one step checkout

Tags: magento2

[image]I want to remove textfield from magento2 checkout field.i am using the IWD free one step extenstion.here with i attach the screenshot of my checkout page.(kindly refer)[image]

Comment: Why do you want to remove email?

Comment: I want to customize the checkout page like the image i attached recently.kindly please refer it and guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Please open the layout file of your module.

Get the name of component and use below code to remove component.

```
 <item name="name_of_componet" xsi:type="array">
  <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="string">true</item>
 </item>
```

Comment: how to get component name?

Comment: ispect element and get the name

Comment: i add this code into my module layout onepage_index_index.xml.but nothing is change in checkout page.

Comment: I can't find exact layout file in IWD one step checkout.can you please give some ideas.

Comment: hi @manjulak, you have installed the extension. please raise the issue with extension support, i have added code for default magento2 checkout